# Visual Studio Test results file

Tags: visual-studio-2017, specflow, gherkin, picklesdoc

I can't find the place where VS 2017 keeps the test result file. I have a lot of Specflow tests which are running fine but i want to find the place where VS is keeping the results. I am using a Library called Pickles which generates documentation from specflow, so it was be accessed via an HTML page. This library needs the VS test results file to add info about which tests are passing etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since SpecFlow is just generating unit tests under the hood, if you run those tests from visual studio 2017 it does not generate test result files.

Instead, you need to use the [vstest.console.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/vstest-console-options?view=vs-2017) command line interface to run the tests.